# How to get a specific text from a textbox and transfer to another textbox?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, textbox

I'm trying to get a specific text from one textbox and put it to another textbox. Been searching for a while and all I can get is the whole text out of that text box.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a `TextBox` or `RichTextBox`?

Comment: From RichTextBox to TextBox.

Comment: If I understand right you are going to copy text fragment from the `RichTextBox` to `TextBox`. How the text fragment in the `RichTextBox` is specified- by cursor? by selection?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's both TextBox, TextBox1 to TextBox2. Btw, Data from the TextBox1 came from SerialPort1.

Comment: You have to parse the text from the `TextBox` to get needed information.

Answer (score 0):

Proper modern design would be if you'd separate your data (the model) from the way that you display your date (the view).

If you separate, it will be easy to reuse this model and view it differently: in a table? or a text file? It will be easier to unit test, because your model is independent from winforms, and usually the code is smaller, so it will be easier to read and to change.

So your model has have two items: one full input text, and a Temperature. We don't know yet what type the temperature is: a string, or maybe a number? Is it in Celsius or Kelvin? Because we separated the model from the view, we don't really need to know this.

So first you need something to read your Input Text.

```
string GetInputText()
{
    return this.textBoxInput.Text;
}
```

Currently we know this input text is from a textBox, but again: outside the procedure we don't want to know where you get your input text from. If in future version you decide that you get this text from the internet, the rest of your program does not have to change.

Secondly we need a procedure to extract the string representation of the temperature from your input text:

```
string ExtractTemperatureText(string inputText)
{
    ....
}
```

How do you know where the temperature is? Does it always start at the 76th character of the inputText? or maybe if is the text after `TBody =`  in line 15? Since you didn't specify, I can't write the code. Again: the nice thing is that only this procedure has to change if you decide to change the format of your input text.

Ok, so we are able to get the input text (from whatever source), and extract the temperature as text (whatever format the input text has).

```
decimal ParseTemperature(string temperatureText)
{
    return decimal.Parse(temparutureText);
}
```

If later you decide that 'C' is part of the Temperature text, and that you will also support 'F' and 'K', changes will only in this procedure.

Finally the method to display the Temperature:

```
void DisplayTemperature(decimal temperature)
{
    // What format?
    this.textBoxTemperature.Text = temperature.ToString("f3");
}
```

Again: this is the only method that has to change if you later decide to support F and K

```
void ProcessInputTemperature();
{
    DisplayTemperature(ParseTemperature(ExtractTemperatureText(GetInputText())));
}
```

Put it all together:

```
void OnButtonOk_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.ProcessInputTemperature();
}
```

See, I even separated your input button from the model: if you want it from a meny click, or on load form, or whatever: only one place to change.

Besides: all other methods will be unit testable, without a form.